# Facebook.init, Facebook.login triggering popup blocker

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api, popup

In Flash I'm calling authenticate first after constructing, how to avoid popup blocker.

```
public function FacebookProxy(appID:String, permissions:Object) {
        this.appID = appID;
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    public function authenticate():void { 
        var response:FacebookAuthResponse = Facebook.getAuthResponse();
        if(response && response.uid) {
            this.success(response);
        } else {
            this.init();
        }
    }

    protected function init():void { 
        Security.loadPolicyFile("https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml");
        Facebook.init(this.appID, this.initHandler);
    }

    protected function initHandler(response:FacebookAuthResponse, fail:Object):void {
        if(response && response.uid){ 
            this.success(response);
        } else { 
            setTimeout(this.login, 200);
        }
    }

    protected function login():void {
        Facebook.login(loginHandler, this.permissions);
    }

    protected function loginHandler(response:FacebookAuthResponse, fail:Object):void {
        if(response && response.uid) {
            this.success(response);
        } else {
            //ExternalInterface.call("trace", "code:" + fail.error.code + ", message:" + fail.error.message + ", type:" + fail.error.type);
        }
    }

    protected function success(response:FacebookAuthResponse):void {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know flash, but you cant call `Facebook.init, Facebook.login` automatically, it will be caught by popup blockers.

Fire these two methods on users activity only i.e. on a click of user.

Comment: but authenticate is getting called on user activity (click) which checks for session and triggers init and login if it can't find the session. it's a series of actions triggered by click,

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, the most frictionless way of logging into Facebook (going by game apps, no popular, and one permissions screen) is to log in using the js api and pass the details into flash